# py.test and Django DB access except for one test class

Tags: django, pytest

To me it's clear "[How can I give database access to all my tests without the django_db marker?](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-give-database-access-to-all-my-tests-without-the-django-db-marker)"

But I would prefer/need to have several class tests without the DB access. 
How can I exclude classes or methods when `enable_db_access_for_all_tests` is active for all tests?

Is there a decorator like `@pytest.mark.no_django_db` or other possible solutions?

Thanks!

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible solution for marking your tests would be to use the `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook in your conftest.py and selectively add a marker for those tests where you need db access. This is an example that traverses all the collected tests and add a marker to them.

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    # Do some filtering to items
    for item in items:
        item.add_marker('django_db')
```

It's safe to use a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` or any other debugging tool at your disposal to check what item looks like.